# Handsontable 0.14.1 + ngHandsontable 0.5.2: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

Tags: handsontable

I am getting this error in IE, but not in Chrome:

"Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference."

The error also shows in their demo page. You can F12 to see the error as you simply moves the mouse:

http://handsontable.github.io/ngHandsontable/

Regards!

Comment: This may be a bug, file it under bugs on the issues page: https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed in github repository. The fix has not been released.

If you need to fix it yourself just as I did, look at:

https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/pull/2448/files

Final fix:

https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/2478